# Laravel : key() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given

Tags: laravel

I want save user id comes with create tag in post create form , but show me this error

**key() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given**

post controller:

```
public function store(PoemsCreateRequest $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $post = Post::create($data);
    if ($post && $post instanceof Post) {
        $tagList = $request->input('tags');
        $tags = collect($tagList)->mapToGroups(function (string $tag) {
            return Tag::firstOrCreate(['name' => $tag, 'author' => Auth::id()])->id;
        })->all();
        return redirect()->back();
    }

}
```

how to fix it?

Comment: Can we see a full stack trace on what line of yours it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure that you passed into the `mapToGroups()` function is returning an int, which is not correct. It must return an array.

[From the documentation:](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-maptogroups)

> The `mapToGroups` method groups the collection's items by the given callback. The callback should return an associative array containing a single key / value pair, thus forming a new collection of grouped values